# How to change my script from an input in python

Tags: python, string, dataframe, opencv, input

I have a list of images with the following names 47A, 33B, 2C, etc all alphnumeric with characters length until 10. The extension of all images is .png

I've created a python program to read one by one this images and extract information (contours area etc etc ). To do this, inside the script I always use the replacement crtl + H to change the names in the following codes:

```
#open image
img = cv2.imread("A.png", 0)   in this case A is the name of an image

#save image
cv2.imwrite("A_copy.png", img) 

#assign name into ID column
dframe['ID'] = 'A'


#save data into this path
dframe.to_csv(r'D:\\NBC_new2020_\\data\\A_data.txt', index = False, sep='\t')
```

I'm trying to open an image, save image, assign name to ID column and save the dataframe by changing the A to 47B and run the program then for 33B and run the program etc etc with  replace crtl + H in the script.

For the moment is the only way to change it.

Is there any other way to change it? I was trying with the following code:

```
A = input('Insert the name of file in png extension:')
A = str(A)
47
img = cv2.imread("A.png", 0)  

###########################################################
```

The A value is considered as a string but the program doesn"t allow to run it well

I would like to know how to replace the "A" as an input before start the python program (like ask me as an input)

Someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `"A.png"` with `A + ".png"`.

When inside quotes, everything is treated as their literal string value. You can concatenate strings with the plus operator to use variables.

Comment: in this case.... dframe.to_csv(r'D:\\NBC_new2020_\\data\\A_data.txt', index = False, sep='\t')... can I apply the same way?

Comment: Yes you could - `'D:\\NBC_new2020_\\data\\' + A + '_data.txt'`
You should also read about f strings in python, which can be more elegant.